# Legacy PHP urls do not invoke custom routing in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

We recently replaced an old php website with an asp.net MVC website.  In order to prevent 404 errors from the legacy urls in search engines, we setup a custom legacy route system via - http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/108/Handling-Legacy-URLs-with-ASP.NET-MVC

The code works on my local machine, and it redirects to the correct route; however, the live server issues a 404.  Bonus problem/clue, the 404 is not our custom 404 page but the iis 6 default page.

**The code:**

```
public class LegacyUrlRoute: RouteBase
{
    // source: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/108/Handling-Legacy-URLs-with-ASP.NET-MVC
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        const string status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        var legacyUrl = request.Url.ToString();
        var newUrl = "";

        if (legacyUrl.Contains(".php"))
        {

            newUrl = "/";
            if (legacyUrl.Contains("support/mailfilter.php"))
                newUrl = "/support/";
            else if (legacyUrl.Contains("/support/default.php"))
                newUrl = "/support/";
            else if (legacyUrl.Contains("/business/default.php"))
                newUrl = "/services/";
            else if (legacyUrl.Contains("/residential/default.php"))
                newUrl = "/services/";
            else if (legacyUrl.Contains("/about/default.php"))
                newUrl = "/home/about/";
            else if (legacyUrl.Contains("/jobs.php"))
                newUrl = "/jobs/";
            else if (legacyUrl.Contains("/support/links.php"))
                newUrl = "/support/";
            else if (legacyUrl.Contains("/support/settings.php"))
                newUrl = "/support/";
            else if (legacyUrl.Contains("/default.php"))
                newUrl = "/";


            response.Status = status;
            response.RedirectLocation = newUrl;
            response.End();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

We suspect that the problem is with iis being unable to serve php pages, but I can't seem to find a setting in iis to fix the problem.  It is as if the request never hits the Controller code, error or otherwise.  All other pages/routing is working perfectly.

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: You most likely need to either a) have IIS handle all incoming request or b) map .php to the aspnet_isapi.dll so that when a request for that file type comes in, IIS sends it to the .NET handler which will then proceed to hit your controller/routing engine.  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Why don't you use the HTTP redirects module in IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

The problem is due to the fact that iis never starts the asp.net service if the extension is .php.

The solution is to go to Properties>Home Directory>Configuration, find the .php extension, change the executable path to the asp.net path, and limit it to "GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" or whatever you prefer.  I originally selected the "All Verbs" radio button, but that did not work.

Though the page did not specifically have the answer I came up with, [this page](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) did help.

Comment: well crap, i should have submitted my comment as an answer :P

Comment: You are right, sorry about that.  I had typed the answer and then saw your comment :(  Had I not found the answer on my own, your comment/answer would have pointed me in the right direction for sure.